# How can I automatically create a shopping list from a weekly .csv file using Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, shopify, powerquery

I've recently started a business, and use Shopify to handle orders.
Shopify creates a .csv file containing all order information needed.
Within this .csv file are two columns of interest, the 'Date to ship' and the 'uniqueID' columns (that contains unique identifiers for each item purchased)

Currently, I am having to manually update quantities on a spreadsheet of each uniqueID, and my spreadsheet will then use these unique IDs to calculate a list of ingredients I need to purchase.

Therein lies my question. I am looking for a way to take my weekly .csv order file from shopify, parse and remove columns not of interest, and then use the uniqueIDs to calculate a 'shopping list'
I have tried using the Power Query editor for removing unnecessary columns, and this works great, but I don't want to have to apply all of the steps (there are a lot) manually to each .csv file that I get weekly, so is there a way to almost 'preload' a set of applied steps I have already determined?

I am also struggling to understand how I can then read the values from this csv file that is robust enough to read any weekly CSV file. What I would be inclined to do would be to have a 'Formula' book, that reads certain values from the 'Orders' book (the one containing the dates and uniqueIDs from the Power Query editor) and then uses ingredient lists and the unique IDs to calculate my shopping list. However, I've found that while this works for one csv file, if I then delete it and try to insert the new week CSV file, it messes up the formula references.

I don't have much experience in Python, and my Brother (who I am implementing this for) would prefer an excel solution, if one exists.

TL:DR - Is there a way, using excel, that every week I can import a .csv file given to me by shopify, delete all of the columns but UniqueID and date automatically, and then have formulas read the required IDs and spit out a shopping list of what I need to buy for that week?

Thanks a lot!
Benn

I have tried Power Queries, but can't get the applied steps to apply automatically to a new weekly CSV file.
I have also set up a sheet that does what I want for the current CSV file, but breaks when I try to update it to the new weekly file due to formula references changing etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use powerquery, you can (a) Save the weekly CSV file over the previous weeks CSV file so that the file name is constant, then create powerquery code that work on that specific file (b) you can use a cell in the excel file and place the filename of the CSV file in there, and get powerquery to work on the file that is specified

For (b) create a range name in excel for a cell, and put the filepath in there

[image]

Read that cell in place of hardcoding the formula.

so that in home ... advanced editor ...

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
```

becomes

```
let Filename= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filepath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Filename),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
```

For the rest of it, load the ingredient list by SKU in one query, then in the other CSV query, merge in the first query and get ingredients for each SKU. You can then right click the ingredients column and group by .. to adding up the ingredients across SKUs